# How to deal with incorrect json format ? (simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0))

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

1) A script that I had working for many weeks broke a few days ago. I can't parse the JSON properly now. So this is not net new code, it's something that has been in operation for months.

2) Something changed in the servicing website, and it's making the JSON non-compliant but I have been trying to circumvent the issue with no success. I think it may be an extra space or something, but I can't change the information returned from the servicing website.

3) I know the json is not compliant because I used a validator (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) by putting the URL of the service I need with my credentials/format needed, and I get proper results but the validation fails with "Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.[Code 29, Structure 0]". There is a way to tell the validator not to validate and the Json looks proper, but Python will not have anything to do with it. When I run my script it reports:
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

4) Below is my URL entry manually and the script. I have obfuscated all sensitive and personal information so the URL if you try won't work, but when I do the non-obfuscated format, I do get a JSON response.

5) Manual URL (obfuscated): 
https://mystuff.mydevices.com/Membership/SomeOtherURLrelated?appId=BB8pQgg123450WHahgl12345nAkkX67890q2HrHD7H1nabcde5KqtN654321LB%2fi&securityToken=null&username=myemail@somedomain.com&password=mypassword&culture=en

6) If I manually opened a browser and put the previous real URL (unmodified), the browser responds with json. An example (obfuscated):
{"UserId":0,"SecurityToken":"abcdb8c3-1ef1-1110-1234-402a914f52aa","ReturnCode":"0","ErrorMessage":"","BrandId":2,"BrandName":"Mydevicebrandname","RegionId":1}

7) What can I do to overcome this ? any suggestions ?  I have been reading and testing but no luck!

8) Now the script (obfuscated) that basically builds the previous URL and extracts from the JSON a one-time security token that then I can use for other purposes in a much bigger application:

```
import json,requests


APPID    = 'BB8pQgg123450WHahgl12345nAkkX67890q2HrHD7H1nabcde5KqtN654321LB%2fi'
USERNAME = 'myemail@somedomain.com'
PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
CULTURE  = 'en'
SERVICE  = 'https://mystuff.mydevices.com'

def get_token_formydevices():   
    payload = {'appId': APPID,
               'securityToken': 'null',
               'username': USERNAME,
               'password': PASSWORD,
               'culture': CULTURE,}
    login_url = SERVICE + '/Membership/SomeOtherURLrelated'
    try:
        r = requests.get(login_url, params=payload)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        return       

    data = r.json()
    if data['ReturnCode'] != '0':
        print(data['ErrorMessage'])
        sys.exit(1)
    return data['SecurityToken']

tokenneeded = get_token_formydevices()

print tokenneeded
```

9) When I run the previous code this is what I get back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testtoken.py", line 33, in <module>
    tokenneeded = get_token_formydevices()
  File "testtoken.py", line 26, in get_token_formydevices
    data = r.json()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 826, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Instead of `r.json()`, use `r.content` or `r.text` so you can see exactly what is being returned. I'm guessing it's going to be HTML or just nothing. If it looks like JSON then post what you can here.

Comment: using either r.content or r.text I get back something like this:

$ python testtoken.py 
<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>Your request has been denied.<br><br>[11679954572637177442]</body></html>

Comment: Sounds like your credentials expired. Maybe contact them.

Comment: I am not sure that's the case. The provider does not use authentication token, they use straight up username/password. When I submit the URL manually into my web browser, I get back a Json response. 

Problem is either that the python code that I am using to make the call is not correct, or that there is a problem parsing the results (seems the former).

It may be that my problem is that the call I am making is wrong but following the vendor's API directly and copying their code snippet and modifying the different attritubes as expected provides the same result (Request has been denied).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and want to share.

So I was very puzzled by the fact that I could open the servicing URL in a web browser and get some json back, but I couldn't do it in my script or even just using cURL.  I kept on getting "request denied" even though the request worked from the browser, so it had to be something else.

So I started experimenting and sending in the request user agent information in my script and voilá!   the code below is working although I obfuscated the original URL and my credentials for protection.

I further want to explain that I was doing this as the servicing URL provides back a one-time token that I can then use to trigger another action. So I needed this routine and executive for as many times I need to carry on specific actions, so all I wanted was to retrieve the token from the json form that url. Hope this makes more sense now with the code below.

```
import json,urllib2
url='https://mystuff.mydevices.com/Membership/SomeOtherURLrelated?appId=BB8pQgg123450WHahgl12345nAkkX67890q2HrHD7H1nabcde5KqtN654321LB%2fi&securityToken=null&username=myemail@somedomain.com&password=mypassword&culture=en'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
#request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36')   # <--- this works too
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
data = json.loads(str(urllib2.urlopen(request).read()))
token = data["SecurityToken"]
print token
```